# API weather undefined. How do I create an IF statment in App Scripts

Tags: javascript

I downloaded a weather API to get the value of the current conditions, which all works well except for the alert "event" and "description".

If an "alert" exists I get the value, but when there is none, the result is "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

What I need is an IF statement that says "if undefined, "0" else get the value" for these two lines:

```js
const alerts = resJSON["alerts"][0]["event"] 
const alertDs = resJSON["alerts"][0]["description"]
```

Comment: `const  alerts = resJSON.alerts ?  resJSON.alerts : {}; const alertEvent = alerts.event || 'default';`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
const resJSON = {alerts: [{notevent: "test", description: "my description"}]};
const alerts = resJSON?.alerts?.[0]?.event || "0";
const alertDs = resJSON?.alerts?.[0]?.description || "0";
console.log(alerts);
console.log(alertDs);
```

Comment: Thank you James, unfortunately, it only gives me a 0 and "my description".  could it be because I'm in App script and your strings are in Java?

Comment: I included a sample `resJSON` response to illustrate how optional chaining works.  In your code I would expect resJSON to be the JSON response from your api call.  So, definitely don't use the first line of my example in your production code.

Comment: That solved the problem.  I didn't realise it was an example, I had changed the name istead of resJSON and ran a console.log on it and it would return the API log for the alerts.  Thank you once again, your help was greatly appreciated.